# Sonarqube: cannot execute Checkstyle

Tags: java, maven, build, azure-pipelines, maven-3

I am using a sonarqube plugin (version 3.9.1.2184) in an azure devOpds build pipeline with Java 17.0.6 and a maven compiler of version 3.10.1. They are running as a maven task with SonarQubeRunAnalysis = true.

When using the old style switch statement, sonarqube flags it as a code smell and recommends using the new java 13/14 switch expression syntax.

I've tried using the new syntax, whether its using the arrow syntax, using commas and a colon with the version that uses "yield", or just using a return in place of yield to address the code smell but each one leads to the error below during the build stage:

"Can not execute Checkstyle: Exception thrown while processing {someFilePathInMyCode} IllegalStateException occured while parsing file {someFilePathInMyCode} expecting COLON, found -> [Help 1]"

The sonar rule I am trying to satisfy is S6208 and here is the link to the rule https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-6208

Any idea on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is actually what you need to understand:

1. Maven Checkstyle Plugin is "a bit" behind the schedule, currently it's most recent version uses Checkstyle 9.3 which was released more than a year ago, since that a plenty of changes were introduced in [Checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/releasenotes.html), most probably you need to [upgrade version of Checkstyle](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html)
2. rules imposed by sonarqube are just a private opinion of sonarqube developers, nothing more, nothing else, unfortunately they use obsessive language in their reports: code do not smell if I use colon instead of comma in switch statement.